# Problem about system of points and segments in space

Tags: geometry, induction

Ii am thinking now about this problem:

There are $200$ points in space.  Each two of them are connected by a segment, and the segments do not intersect with each other.  Each segment is colored in one of $K$ colors. Peter wants to paint each point in one of these colors so that there are no two points and a segment between them painted in the same color.  Will Peter always succeed if
a) $K = 7$;  b) $K = 10$?

I know, how to prove a) by induction, but i have no idea about b).

$\underline{\text{Proof of a).}}$ Let us prove by induction the following statement: if the number of colors is $n$ and the number of points is at least $2^n$, then the answer is no.

The base ($n = 1$) is obvious.

Induction step. Divide the points into two sets, each consisting of at least $2^{n-1}$ points. In each of the sets, color the segments with $n - 1$ colors in accordance with the inductive hypothesis. All the segments connecting points from different sets will be colored with the remaining color.  If in any of the two sets there are no points painted in the last color, then the "bad" segment exists by the induction hypothesis. If in both sets there are points of the last color, then the segment connecting them is "bad".

Can you help me with b)? I will appreciate any ideas for proving.